# Sometimes getting java.net.ConnectException

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, networking

I have a stable API processing thousands of requests per day.

Request QPS is about 30 requests per second, and the peak value of request is up to 300 QPS. However, the server can totally cover such pressure.

But I found it a strange situation that I will get several exceptions of these two:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

for about 2-4 errors per day in up to 30,000,000 requests, and I don't know what's going on and how to fix it.

I think,if this situation is just due to network fluctuations, is it acceptable to be ignored.

Comment: both `Connection refused` and `Connection reset` are typically caused by the other side of the connection when they send a TCP "RST" packet. During connect (=refused) or later mid way into the connection (=reset). Unless you can identify a certain access pattern of your application that essentially causes a denial of service attack on the target there's not much you can do on your side

Comment: It's normal, it happens with server, but acceptable or not depends on your application (a bank would not accept 0.00001% of transfers to simply disappear), the fix to this would be a retry strategy.

Comment: @zapl Thanks a lot! In this situation, I have no need to include retry strategy, it is OK to tell customers only refresh the page.